# following code crashes in 64 bit system

Tags: c

Following program crashes in 64 bit system. This code is working fine in 32 bit system
I am using centOS 32 bit and centOS 64 bit sytems.. 
what will be the reason for this ?

```
#if 1
if (1) 
{
  memset(message1, '\0', sizeof(message1));
  vsprintf(message1, format, vAList);
}
#endif

if (1)
{
  //PROGRAM CRASHES in the following line IF AM PUTTING #if 1 in the above code as i did
  val = vfprintf(logFile, format,vAList);
}
```

when program reaches    `val = vfprintf(logFile,format,vAList);`

here it crashes in 64 bit system..

Comment: Please also share what you learned while trying to debug this problem, such as where the crash occurred and the values of the variables at the point of the crash.

Comment: Does the compiler generate any warnings?  Add them in to the question or resolve them first.

Comment: Try to give at least the backtrace of the debugger (in `gdb` type simply `bt` when you have reached the crash).

Comment: Wait, this code is completely different from the code you posted originally. No wonder nobody could see the problem!

Comment: i modified the question after getting the answer.. i thought this will be helpful for others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a variadic argument list twice. `vfprintf` "uses up" the arguments and the next call probably tries to access memory after the list. In the words of the man page:

> These functions [`v*printf`] do not call the `va_end` macro. Consequently, the value of ap is undefined after the  call.  The application should call `va_end(ap)` itself afterwards.

If your format requires dereferencing, like the `%s` format, chances are that your program crashes.

You can solve that in two ways: Either wrap all calls to `vfprintf` in their own `va_start` and `va_end`:

```
int f(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list va;

    va_start(va, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, va);
    va_end(va);

    va_start(va, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, va);
    va_end(va);

    return 0;
}
```

Or make a copy of the variadic list:

```
int f(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list va, vb;

    va_start(va, fmt);
    va_copy(vb, va);

    vprintf(fmt, va);
    vprintf(fmt, vb);

    va_end(va);
    va_end(vb);

    return 0;
}
```

(You must make the copy before the list you copy from has been used.)

**Edit**: Forgot to clean up the copied va lis, `vb` in the second example. Fixed now.

Comment: why this is then not crashing in 32 bit ?

Comment: Coincidence - you got lucky. (The fact that it doesn't crash doesn't necessarily mean it's correct.)